# failled to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to install a virtual machine with VM virtual box in my HP ZBook 15, but it doesn't work, I receive this message

Login failed for vm-BD6-fall 2019 virtual machine.

Not in a partition hypervisor (HVP = 0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Error Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: Did that work or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do exactly what it says.  Virtualization support at the processor level is disabled.

Reboot.. very first thing after power on:

1. Hit F10
2. Setup -> Advanced -> System Options
3. Virtualization Technology menu.
4. Enable from there.

If for some reason, you are having trouble getting into the BIOS screen via F10, you can google "How to Enter the BIOS on a Windows 10 PC" or similar for how to do that.  I find hitting the function key at startup easier.